# How to change JavaScript module name generated by Swagger Codegen?

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm using Swagger Codegen to generate a JavaScript client:

```
swagger-codegen generate -i http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs \
-l javascript -o subscreasy-javascript-client
```

The name of the generated module is `api-documentation`.

How can I configure `swagger-codegen` so that it generates the JavaScript module with a custom name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swagger Codegen generators have language-specific options. To see the supported options, run codegen with the `config-help` argument:

```
swagger-codegen config-help -l javascript
```

Output:

```
CONFIG OPTIONS
        ...
        invokerPackage
            root package for generated code

        apiPackage
            package for generated api classes

        modelPackage
            package for generated models

        projectName
            name of the project (Default: generated from info.title or "swagger-js-client")

        moduleName
            module name for AMD, Node or globals (Default: generated from <projectName>)
        ...
```

You can pass the values for these options as `-Dname=value`. Assuming you want to change the `moduleName`:

```
swagger-codegen generate -i http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs \
-l javascript -o subscreasy-javascript-client \
-DmoduleName=my-custom-module-name
```